# Keeping extra script tags in compiled svelte code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, svelte, rollupjs

I am currently having a svelte program that gets compiled to the corresponding, js and css files, which I am using in a separate html template string. That is getting used as part of an application's webview - it basically gets put into a iframe at the end inside that application.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta chatset='UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src img-src https: data:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' ${webview.cspSource}; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="${styleResetUri}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="${styleMainUri}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="${styleMainPanel}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script nonce="${nonce}">
            const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main><App/></main>
        <script src="${scriptMainPanel}" nonce="${nonce}" />
        <script src="${gramJS}" nonce="${nonce}" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I have my rollup config setup such that whatever is in my svelte folders gets compiled to js and css as said above which I import in the lines.

The line `<script src="${scriptMainPanel}" nonce="${nonce}" />` and `<link href="${styleMainPanel}" rel="stylesheet">` are the places where I am importing the compiled code. Similarly, my css gets imported.

**Notice** that I am using the  tag as the place to mount my app like so,

```js
import App from "../components/MainPanel.svelte";

const app = new App({
    target: document.getElementsByTagName("App")[0],
});

export default app;
```

### The Issue

It all works perfectly fine - it renders fine and all. But, the issue I am facing is that, the `<script src="${gramJS}" nonce="${nonce}" />` that I have in the `body` of the `html` code above, is not seen finally. Is it that `svelte` removes all other tags? I have seen this normally if I have other `p`, `h1` or other `html` tags in the `body`, they get removed - but I have targeted `App` here, so it should not get removed yeah?

If not is there any other way to include my script in that html? Maybe include it inside the pre-compiled files so that it stays even after the compiling?

**Note** That extra script import is itself a minified script as it is node and some reason I am not able to use it within svelte.

**--Update 1--**

After inspecting the rendered HTML, I have found that the extra script tag `<script src="${gramJS}" nonce="${nonce}" />` gets shifted inside the script tag `<script src="${scriptMainPanel}" nonce="${nonce}" />`. I do not understand why, more like any other tags in the html gets pushed into the script that references the compiled svelte code.

Comment: You are not showing how you actually "render" the HTML template, but I don't think svelte is doing anything with it. The problem is likely that you are self-closing the `<script>` elements. Those are not self-closing elements, you always need a proper end tag: `<script ...></script>`. Give that a try.

Comment: Oh! great I will try that out. But I do not render it. I just return this html template string which gets passed onto the vscode extension webview. I don't control it much. But, you see if I just enter normal html elements inside that body tag without the compiled svelte scripts, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I found out something after inspecting the rendered html, which I have update.

Comment: Hey @FelixKling. You literally solved my problem. I converted them to `<script></script>` tags and it works like charm. Feel free to add an answer and I would be able to mark it up. Thank you so much. You just cleared the issue I had for 3 days now. <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<script>` elements cannot be self-closing. I don't know how the browser corrects that but I suspect that the two script tags somehow interfere with each other.

Use a proper closing tag for both elements:

```
<script src="${scriptMainPanel}" nonce="${nonce}"></script>
<script src="${gramJS}" nonce="${nonce}"></script>
```